# Showing default Icon when installing app from google play

Tags: android, xml, icons

My problem is when I install my app from android studio it's showing the icon I made
but when I install it from Google Play it's showing the default icon of Android

I recorded from my phone please check it
When i install from android studio:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bWFxrmnMoJ1JyxWRlWRWS9d4wzwQ6i6z/view?usp=share_link
When i install from google play:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bRa8UvseRpbvnpPZHDq2cqB_dL3iZIwa/view?usp=share_link

I tried to remove the icon from Google and upload it again
than I deleted the existing icon from mipmap and add it again but nothing changed

Comment: Does it happen with both debug and release install from Android Studio?

Answer (score -1):

Please check out below video, change image asset from debug to main

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52wKo4rNG_o

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).